# core data simple fetch request template

Tags: core-data

I have a small core data base "Guests" and I am trying to get the results from a fetch request template called FetchRequestA, I made a button to trigger in the console the results from the request but I keep on getting a null answer, the request is set to display all guestlastnames that contain a d ? here is the code that i am using :

```
- (IBAction)fetchA:(id)sender {

    NSFetchRequest *request2 = [[[self managedObjectModel] fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"FetchRequestA"] copy];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"guestlastname" ascending:YES];

    [request2 setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sort, nil];

    [request2 setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error];


    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {


        NSLog(@"problem %@", error);

    }

    for (Guests *guestlastname in fetchedObjects) {

     NSLog(@"Fetched Object =  %@", guestlastname.guestlastname);
 }
}
```

Am I missing a method ? have perused around but to no avail, thanks in advance.

Comment: ok…so after much searching finally found way, here is code that i am using now and is returning my predicate results in log and in a label :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution :

- (IBAction)gettemplatebutton:(id)sender {

  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

  NSManagedObjectModel* model = [[context persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel];

  NSDictionary* dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys: self.fetchedObjects, @"guestlastname",nil];

  NSFetchRequest* request2 = [model fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:@"FetchRequestA" substitutionVariables: dict];

  NSError* error = nil;

  NSArray *Guests2 = [context executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error];

  NSString *g3 = @"";

  for(NSManagedObject *guestlastname in Guests2)

  {
   g3 = [g3 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", [guestlastname valueForKey:@"guestlastname"]]];
   }

  self.displaytemplateLabel.text = g3;

  [_displaytemplateLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

  for (NSManagedObject *guestlastname in Guests2)

  {
    {
         NSLog(@"%@", [guestlastname valueForKey:@"guestlastname"]);
      }
  }
  }

and added  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *fetchedObjects; in header file.